# A way to generalize Haskell's Either type for arbitrarily many types?

Tags: haskell, types, either, parametric-polymorphism

I am creating a turn based game. I want to define a datatype that encodes one type out of many possible types. Here is the motivating example:

I have defined a `Turn` type using GADTs, so the type of each value of `Turn a` says something about it's value.

```
data Travel
data Attack
data Flee
data Quit

data Turn a where
   Travel :: Location -> Turn Travel
   Attack :: Int -> Turn Attack
   Flee :: Turn Flee
   Quit :: Turn Quit
```

Now I can write types like this `decideTravel :: GameState -> Turn Travel`, very expressive and nice.

The problem arises when I want to return one of multiple possible turn types. I want to write functions similar to the following:

```
-- OneOf taking two types
decideFightingTurn :: GameState -> OneOf (Turn Attack) (Turn Flee)
-- OneOf takes three types
decideTurn :: GameState -> OneOf (Turn Attack) (Turn Travel) (Turn Quit)
```

Where this `OneOf` datatype carries the notion of "one type out of many possible types". The problem lies in defining this datatype, I need to somehow handle a list of types at the type level.

There are two subpar solutions I have as of now:

#### Solution 1: Create a wrapper sum type

Simply create a new type that has a constructor for each `Turn a` constructor:

```
data AnyTurn
   = TravelTurn (Turn Travel)
   | TravelAttack (Turn Attack)
   | TravelFlee (Turn Flee)
   | TravelQuit (Turn Quit)
```

This doesn't help me in the way I want it to. Now I have to pattern match all cases of `AnyTurn` and account for invalid input types. Additionally the type level information is obscured by the `AnyTurn` type, since it fails to indicate which specific turns are actually possible at the type level.

#### Solution 2: Create "Either" types for different numbers of types

This solution gives me what I want at the type level, but is cumbersome to use. Basically create an `Either`-like type for any number of combinations, like so:

```
data OneOf2 a b
   = OneOf2A a
   | OneOf2B b

data OneOf3 a b c
   = OneOf3A a
   | OneOf3B b
   | OneOf3C c

-- etc, for as many as are needed.
```

This conveys what I want at the type level, so I can now write the previous examples as:

```
decideFightingTurn :: GameState -> OneOf2 (Turn Travel) (Turn Flee)
decideTurn :: GameState -> OneOf3 (Turn Attack) (Turn Travel) (Turn Quit)
```

This works, however it would be nice to express this with just one type `OneOf`. Is there any way to write the generalized `OneOf` type in Haskell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this, I guess:

```
data OneOf as where
    ThisOne :: a -> OneOf (a : as)
    Later :: OneOf as -> OneOf (a : as)
```

Then you can write, for example:

```
decideFightingTurn :: GameState -> OneOf [Turn Travel, Turn Flee]
```

You might also like to:

```
type family Map f xs where
    Map f '[] = '[]
    Map f (x:xs) = f x : Map f xs
```

This way you can write something like:

```
decideFightingTurn :: GameState -> OneOf (Map Turn [Travel, Flee])
```

Or you could build the `Map` into the GADT if you think you'll always be doing it:

```
data OneOfF f as where
    ThisOneF :: f a -> OneOfF f (a : as)
    LaterF :: OneOfF f as -> OneOfF f (a : as)
```

And then:

```
decideFightingTurn :: GameState -> OneOfF Turn [Travel, Flee]
```

Various things can be done to make this more efficient if that becomes a concern; the first thing I'd try would be using binary indexing rather than unary as shown here.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Haskell library called [`row-types`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/row-types) that might give you what you want.  Specifically, it provides an [`extensible variant`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/row-types-1.0.1.0/docs/Data-Row-Variants.html) that is kind of like `Either` but tagged and with arbitrarily many options.

In your case, you could make your types:

```hs
import Data.Row

decideFightingTurn :: GameState -> Var ("travel" .== Turn Travel .+ "flee" .== Turn Flee)
decideTurn :: GameState -> Var ("attack" .== Turn Attack .+ "travel" .== Turn Travel .+ "quit" .== Turn Quit)
```

The easiest way to work with variants is to turn `OverloadedLabels` on.  Then, to create one, you write:

```hs
decideFightingTurn gs = case gs of
  Foo -> IsJust #travel $ Travel loc
  Bar -> IsJust #flee Flee
```

Deconstructing can be done in a few different ways.  If you just want to check for a particular type, you can use `trial` or `view` (exported by `Data.Row.Variants`), but if you want to deal with all the options at once, you may want to use `switch`.  You'd write something like this:

```hs
handleTravelOrFlee :: Var ("travel" .== Turn Travel .+ "flee" .== Turn Flee) -> GameState -> GameState
handleTravelOrFlee v gs = switch v $
     #travel .== (\(Travel loc) -> updateGameStateWithLoc gs loc)
  .+ #flee   .== (\Flee -> updateGameStateFlee gs)
```

Check out the documentation and [the examples file](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/row-types-1.0.1.0/src/examples/Examples.lhs) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be activating and deactivating constructors in the sum type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeOperators, DataKinds, PolyKinds, 
             TypeFamilies, StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Werror=incomplete-patterns -Werror=overlapping-patterns #-}
import Data.Void
import Data.Kind

data TurnType =
      Travel
    | Attack
    | Flee
    | Quit

type Turn :: TurnType -> Type
data Turn tt  where
   TurnTravel :: Location -> Turn Travel
   TurnAttack :: Int -> Turn Attack
   TurnFlee :: Turn Flee
   TurnQuit :: Turn Quit

type X :: TurnType -> [TurnType] -> Type
type family X x tts :: Type where
    X _ '[] = Void 
    X x (x : xs) = ()
    X x (_ : xs) = X x xs

-- Exhaustiveness checker knows that branches where
-- X returns Void are impossible.
type AnyTurn :: [TurnType] -> Type
data AnyTurn allowed
   = TravelTurn !(X Travel allowed) (Turn Travel)
   | TravelAttack !(X Attack allowed) (Turn Attack)
   | TravelFlee  !(X Flee allowed) (Turn Flee)
   | TravelQuit  !(X Quit allowed) (Turn Quit)
```

Putting it to work:

```
someTurn :: AnyTurn '[Travel, Attack]
someTurn = TravelAttack () (TurnAttack 0)

-- This doesn't give an exhaustiveness error because other branches are impossible.
-- The problem is that we now have those annoying () cluttering every match.
turn2string :: AnyTurn '[Travel, Attack] -> String
turn2string t = case t of
   TravelTurn () _ -> "foo" 
   TravelAttack () _ -> "bar"
   -- TravelQuit _ _ -> "doesn't compile"
```

Comment: I like it. You can eliminate the `()`s by making it a constraint. For example, `type family Elem x xs where Elem x [] = False; Elem x (x:xs) = True; Elem x (_:xs) = Elem x xs` and then `data AnyTurn allowed where AnyTurn :: Elem x allowed ~ True => Turn x -> AnyTurn`.